# UWP Camera CaptureElement displaying on 50% of screen

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone, uwp, uwp-xaml

I am writing a **UWP application**.It's like a simple custom camera with Taking PHOTO Button. It includes an XAML view having **captureElement**, and page behind the code.

The issue is that **Camera opens on 50%** of the screen on devices: Lumia 950 and Lumia 950XL as if the Grid containing captureElement is divided into two columns but on other devices, it perfect.

I took help of:
[Microsoft UWP Samples: Camera Sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/CameraStarterKit)

```
    namespace InfoMedia.Views.Posting
{

    public sealed partial class PostingCameraView : BasePage
    {             
        private readonly DisplayInformation _displayInformation = DisplayInformation.GetForCurrentView();
        private readonly SimpleOrientationSensor _orientationSensor = SimpleOrientationSensor.GetDefault();
        private SimpleOrientation _deviceOrientation = SimpleOrientation.NotRotated;
        private DisplayOrientations _displayOrientation = DisplayOrientations.Portrait;


        private static readonly Guid RotationKey = new Guid("C380465D-2271-428C-9B83-ECEA3B4A85C1");
        private StorageFolder _captureFolder = null;
        private readonly DisplayRequest _displayRequest = new DisplayRequest();
        private readonly SystemMediaTransportControls _systemMediaControls = SystemMediaTransportControls.GetForCurrentView();

        // MediaCapture and its state variables
        private MediaCapture _mediaCapture;
        private bool _isInitialized;
        private bool _isPreviewing;

        private bool _mirroringPreview;
        private bool _externalCamera;
        private bool _isRecording;

        private PostingAdViewModel postingAdViewModel;

        #region Constructor, lifecycle, and navigation

        public PostingCameraView()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();

            if (ApplicationHelper.GetInstance().DetectDeviceFamily() == CommonServices.Enums.DeviceType.Phone)
            {
                NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Disabled;

                this.Loaded += PostingCameraView_Loaded;
            }
        }

        private async void PostingCameraView_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            postingAdViewModel.IsCameraInitializing = true;

            await SetupUiAsync();

            await InitializeCameraAsync();

            postingAdViewModel.IsCameraInitializing = false;
        }


        #region Event handlers


        private async void SystemMediaControls_PropertyChanged(SystemMediaTransportControls sender, SystemMediaTransportControlsPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
        {
            await Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, async () =>
            {
                // Only handle this event if this page is currently being displayed
                if (args.Property == SystemMediaTransportControlsProperty.SoundLevel && Frame.CurrentSourcePageType == typeof(MainPage))
                {
                    if (sender.SoundLevel == SoundLevel.Muted)
                    {
                        await CleanupCameraAsync();
                    }
                    else if (!_isInitialized)
                    {
                        await InitializeCameraAsync();
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        private void OrientationSensor_OrientationChanged(SimpleOrientationSensor sender, SimpleOrientationSensorOrientationChangedEventArgs args)
        {
            if (args.Orientation != SimpleOrientation.Faceup && args.Orientation != SimpleOrientation.Facedown)
            {
                _deviceOrientation = args.Orientation;

            }
        }


        private async void DisplayInformation_OrientationChanged(DisplayInformation sender, object args)
        {
            _displayOrientation = sender.CurrentOrientation;

            if (_isPreviewing)
            {
                await SetPreviewRotationAsync();
            }

        }


        #endregion Event handlers


        #region MediaCapture methods

        private async Task InitializeCameraAsync()
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("InitializeCameraAsync");

            if (_mediaCapture == null)
            {
                // Attempt to get the back camera if one is available, but use any camera device if not
                var cameraDevice = await FindCameraDeviceByPanelAsync(Windows.Devices.Enumeration.Panel.Back);

                if (cameraDevice == null)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("No camera device found!");
                    return;
                }

                // Create MediaCapture and its settings
                _mediaCapture = new MediaCapture();

                // Register for a notification when video recording has reached the maximum time and when something goes wrong
                _mediaCapture.RecordLimitationExceeded += MediaCapture_RecordLimitationExceeded;
                _mediaCapture.Failed += MediaCapture_Failed;

                var settings = new MediaCaptureInitializationSettings { VideoDeviceId = cameraDevice.Id };

                // Initialize MediaCapture
                try
                {
                    await _mediaCapture.InitializeAsync(settings);
                    _isInitialized = true;
                }
                catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("Access to the camera is denied. You can change the permissions in mobile settings for camera", "Alert!");
                }

                // If initialization succeeded, start the preview
                if (_isInitialized)
                {
                    // Figure out where the camera is located
                    if (cameraDevice.EnclosureLocation == null || cameraDevice.EnclosureLocation.Panel == Windows.Devices.Enumeration.Panel.Unknown)
                    {
                        // No information on the location of the camera, assume it's an external camera, not integrated on the device
                        _externalCamera = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // Camera is fixed on the device
                        _externalCamera = false;

                        // Only mirror the preview if the camera is on the front panel
                        _mirroringPreview = (cameraDevice.EnclosureLocation.Panel == Windows.Devices.Enumeration.Panel.Front);
                    }

                    await StartPreviewAsync();

                    UpdateCaptureControls();
                }
            }
        }

        private async Task StartPreviewAsync()
        {
            // Prevent the device from sleeping while the preview is running
            _displayRequest.RequestActive();

            // Set the preview source in the UI and mirror it if necessary
            PreviewControl.Source = _mediaCapture;
            PreviewControl.FlowDirection = _mirroringPreview ? FlowDirection.RightToLeft : FlowDirection.LeftToRight;

            // Start the preview
            await _mediaCapture.StartPreviewAsync();
            _isPreviewing = true;

            // Initialize the preview to the current orientation
            if (_isPreviewing)
            {
                await SetPreviewRotationAsync();
            }
        }


        private async Task FocusCameraLens()
        {
            if (_mediaCapture != null)
            {
                if (_isPreviewing)
                {
                    // test if focus is supported
                    if (_mediaCapture.VideoDeviceController.FocusControl.Supported)
                    {
                        // get the focus control from the mediaCapture object
                        var focusControl = _mediaCapture.VideoDeviceController.FocusControl;

                        // try to get full range, but settle for the first supported one.
                        var focusRange = focusControl.SupportedFocusRanges.Contains(AutoFocusRange.FullRange)
                            ? AutoFocusRange.FullRange
                            : focusControl.SupportedFocusRanges.FirstOrDefault();

                        var focusMode = focusControl.SupportedFocusModes.Contains(FocusMode.Auto)
                            ? FocusMode.Auto
                            : focusControl.SupportedFocusModes.FirstOrDefault();

                        focusControl.Configure(
                            new FocusSettings
                            {
                                Mode = focusMode,
                                AutoFocusRange = focusRange
                            });

                        try
                        {
                            // finally wait for the camera to focus
                            await focusControl.FocusAsync();
                        }
                        catch (Exception _focusExp)
                        {
                            //Ignore
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }


        private async Task SetPreviewRotationAsync()
        {
            // Only need to update the orientation if the camera is mounted on the device
            if (_externalCamera) return;

            // Calculate which way and how far to rotate the preview
            int rotationDegrees = ConvertDisplayOrientationToDegrees(_displayOrientation);

            // The rotation direction needs to be inverted if the preview is being mirrored
            if (_mirroringPreview)
            {
                rotationDegrees = (360 - rotationDegrees) % 360;
            }

            // Add rotation metadata to the preview stream to make sure the aspect ratio / dimensions match when rendering and getting preview frames
            var props = _mediaCapture.VideoDeviceController.GetMediaStreamProperties(MediaStreamType.VideoPreview);

            int MFVideoRotation = ConvertVideoRotationToMFRotation(VideoRotation.Clockwise90Degrees);

            // props.Properties.Add(RotationKey, rotationDegrees);
            props.Properties.Add(RotationKey, PropertyValue.CreateInt32(MFVideoRotation));

            await _mediaCapture.SetEncodingPropertiesAsync(MediaStreamType.VideoPreview, props, null);
        }

        int ConvertVideoRotationToMFRotation(VideoRotation rotation)
        {
            int MFVideoRotation = 0; // MFVideoRotationFormat::MFVideoRotationFormat_0 in Mfapi.h
            switch (rotation)
            {
                case VideoRotation.Clockwise90Degrees:
                    MFVideoRotation = 90; // MFVideoRotationFormat::MFVideoRotationFormat_90;
                    break;
                case VideoRotation.Clockwise180Degrees:
                    MFVideoRotation = 180; // MFVideoRotationFormat::MFVideoRotationFormat_180;
                    break;
                case VideoRotation.Clockwise270Degrees:
                    MFVideoRotation = 270; // MFVideoRotationFormat::MFVideoRotationFormat_270;
                    break;
            }

            return MFVideoRotation;
        }


        #endregion MediaCapture methods


        #region Helper functions


        private async Task SetupUiAsync()
        {
            DisplayInformation.AutoRotationPreferences = DisplayOrientations.Portrait;

            if (ApiInformation.IsTypePresent("Windows.UI.ViewManagement.StatusBar"))
            {
                await Windows.UI.ViewManagement.StatusBar.GetForCurrentView().HideAsync();
            }

            _displayOrientation = _displayInformation.CurrentOrientation;
            if (_orientationSensor != null)
            {
                _deviceOrientation = _orientationSensor.GetCurrentOrientation();
            }

            RegisterEventHandlers();

            var picturesLibrary = await StorageLibrary.GetLibraryAsync(KnownLibraryId.Pictures);
            _captureFolder = picturesLibrary.SaveFolder ?? ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;

            this.UpdateLayout();
        }


        private void UpdateCaptureControls()
        {

            postingAdViewModel.IsCaptureButtonEnabled = _isPreviewing;

            if (_isInitialized && !_mediaCapture.MediaCaptureSettings.ConcurrentRecordAndPhotoSupported)
            {
                postingAdViewModel.IsCaptureButtonEnabled = !_isRecording;


                PhotoButton.Opacity = postingAdViewModel.IsCaptureButtonEnabled ? 1 : 0;

            }
        }


        private void RegisterEventHandlers()
        {
            if (ApiInformation.IsTypePresent("Windows.Phone.UI.Input.HardwareButtons"))
            {
                HardwareButtons.CameraPressed += HardwareButtons_CameraPressed;
            }

            if (_orientationSensor != null)
            {
                _orientationSensor.OrientationChanged += OrientationSensor_OrientationChanged;


            }

            _displayInformation.OrientationChanged += DisplayInformation_OrientationChanged;
            _systemMediaControls.PropertyChanged += SystemMediaControls_PropertyChanged;
        }

        private void UnregisterEventHandlers()
        {
            if (ApiInformation.IsTypePresent("Windows.Phone.UI.Input.HardwareButtons"))
            {
                HardwareButtons.CameraPressed -= HardwareButtons_CameraPressed;
            }

            if (_orientationSensor != null)
            {
                _orientationSensor.OrientationChanged -= OrientationSensor_OrientationChanged;
            }

            _displayInformation.OrientationChanged -= DisplayInformation_OrientationChanged;
            _systemMediaControls.PropertyChanged -= SystemMediaControls_PropertyChanged;
        }


        private static async Task<DeviceInformation> FindCameraDeviceByPanelAsync(Windows.Devices.Enumeration.Panel desiredPanel)
        {
            var allVideoDevices = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(DeviceClass.VideoCapture);

            DeviceInformation desiredDevice = allVideoDevices.FirstOrDefault(x => x.EnclosureLocation != null && x.EnclosureLocation.Panel == desiredPanel);

            return desiredDevice ?? allVideoDevices.FirstOrDefault();
        }


        private static async Task ReencodeAndSavePhotoAsync(IRandomAccessStream stream, StorageFile file, PhotoOrientation photoOrientation)
        {
            using (var inputStream = stream)
            {
                var decoder = await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(inputStream);

                using (var outputStream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
                {
                    var encoder = await BitmapEncoder.CreateForTranscodingAsync(outputStream, decoder);

                    var properties = new BitmapPropertySet { { "System.Photo.Orientation", new BitmapTypedValue(photoOrientation, PropertyType.UInt16) } };

                    await encoder.BitmapProperties.SetPropertiesAsync(properties);
                    await encoder.FlushAsync();
                }
            }
        }

        #endregion Helper functions


        #region Rotation helpers

       private SimpleOrientation GetCameraOrientation()
        {
            if (_externalCamera)
            {
                return SimpleOrientation.NotRotated;
            }

            var result = _deviceOrientation;

            if (_displayInformation.NativeOrientation == DisplayOrientations.Portrait)
            {
                switch (result)
                {
                    case SimpleOrientation.Rotated90DegreesCounterclockwise:
                        result = SimpleOrientation.NotRotated;
                        break;
                    case SimpleOrientation.Rotated180DegreesCounterclockwise:
                        result = SimpleOrientation.Rotated90DegreesCounterclockwise;
                        break;
                    case SimpleOrientation.Rotated270DegreesCounterclockwise:
                        result = SimpleOrientation.Rotated180DegreesCounterclockwise;
                        break;
                    case SimpleOrientation.NotRotated:
                        result = SimpleOrientation.Rotated270DegreesCounterclockwise;
                        break;
                }
            }

            if (_mirroringPreview)
            {
                switch (result)
                {
                    case SimpleOrientation.Rotated90DegreesCounterclockwise:
                        return SimpleOrientation.Rotated270DegreesCounterclockwise;
                    case SimpleOrientation.Rotated270DegreesCounterclockwise:
                        return SimpleOrientation.Rotated90DegreesCounterclockwise;
                }
            }

            return result;
        }


        private static int ConvertDeviceOrientationToDegrees(SimpleOrientation orientation)
        {
            switch (orientation)
            {
                case SimpleOrientation.Rotated90DegreesCounterclockwise:
                    return 90;
                case SimpleOrientation.Rotated180DegreesCounterclockwise:
                    return 180;
                case SimpleOrientation.Rotated270DegreesCounterclockwise:
                    return 270;
                case SimpleOrientation.NotRotated:
                default:
                    return 0;
            }
        }

        private static int ConvertDisplayOrientationToDegrees(DisplayOrientations orientation)
        {
            switch (orientation)
            {
                case DisplayOrientations.Portrait:
                    return 90;
                case DisplayOrientations.LandscapeFlipped:
                    return 180;
                case DisplayOrientations.PortraitFlipped:
                    return 270;
                case DisplayOrientations.Landscape:
                default:
                    return 0;
            }
        }

        private static PhotoOrientation ConvertOrientationToPhotoOrientation(SimpleOrientation orientation)
        {
            switch (orientation)
            {
                case SimpleOrientation.Rotated90DegreesCounterclockwise:
                    return PhotoOrientation.Rotate90;
                case SimpleOrientation.Rotated180DegreesCounterclockwise:
                    return PhotoOrientation.Rotate180;
                case SimpleOrientation.Rotated270DegreesCounterclockwise:
                    return PhotoOrientation.Rotate270;
                case SimpleOrientation.NotRotated:
                default:
                    return PhotoOrientation.Normal;
            }
        }



        #endregion Rotation helpers    

    }
}
```

**What is causing this issue?**

Comment: There's a lot of code there for people to look through. Can you try and create a [minimum, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: When page is navigated, and xaml loaded, i search for available camera devices and pickup back camera and initialise it, then start its preview in captureElement control.

Comment: Also, there are suspending and resuming methods, to clear camera object from memory ie, release camera whenever app enters suspend mode and resume camera whenever app is resumed

Comment: Yes, that is helpful. But maybe there is a minimum set of code you can post to reproduce the problem. Then you are more likely to get an answer :)

Comment: On click of TAKE PHOTO button i search for lower resolution and take stream from camera in that resolution and save it into StorageFile and pass that into list binded to GridView

Comment: @DavidRawson
I did minification of the code here. Now please check

Comment: @SheikhAtif what has been suggested to you is to reduce the amount of code and only post what is relevant. You've posted everything rather than just the required methods that you're having a problem with.

Comment: This is the minimum code what Initializes Camera, captureElement and mediaCapture

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

```
var boolean = ApplicationView.TryEnterFullScreenMode();
```

It hides the **soft Navigaiton Bar**, and aspect ratio is maintained to captureElement, and camera works fine